# Controller doesn't read request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two controllers for `Account` and `Pet`. Both have a method marked with the `[HttpPost]` annotation; their objects are passed to the method.

```cs
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private Accounts _accounts;

    public AccountController(Accounts accounts) 
    {
        _accounts = accounts;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registration([FromBody]Account account)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, account.Login),
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookies")));

        if (_accounts.AddAccount(account))
            return Ok("You registered!");
        else 
            return BadRequest("Unable to register user!");
    }
}

[Authorize]
public class PetController : Controller
{
    private Pets _pets;

    public PetController(Pets pets) 
    {
        _pets = pets;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add([FromBody]PetShipping petShipping)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

        if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Username not found! It is impossible to create an animal.");
        }

        _pets.AddPet(user, petShipping.TypePet, petShipping.Name);

        return Ok("You purchased an animal");
    }
}
```

My models classes:

```
public class PetShipping
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public PetType TypePet { get; set; } = PetType.None;
}

public class Account
{
    public string Login { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

In the `AccountController` `Registration()` method, when I pass the model in the form of JSON in Postman, it processes and everything goes well, but when I do the same with `PetController.Add()`, it sees the object as `null`. I don't see what is my mistake.

Can you guide me and give me some advice?

Postman screenshots, `Content-Type = application/json`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weXpR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEgYJ.png)

I looked for this error on the Internet, but all it says is to set the `[FromBody]` attribute, check the `content-type` as `application/json` and check the sent JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of the Enum (PetType) which you used in Pet Shipping, in postman you have to pass the assigned value of each enum members.
for example use this json:

```
{"Name" : "Test","PetType" : 1}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I also found the [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))] attribute for enum field. Thanks!